# Two constructors with same name different parameters entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, partial-classes

I have a partial class `Table1` which is generated by EF and I have created another partial class `Table1` in the same namespace with the same name with some custom properties.

EF has created a parameterless constructor and I need to have one more constructor with some parameters in my custom partial class `Table1`. But my code is complaining:

> member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Is there a workaround for this?

The EF generated code for `Table1` looks like:

```
public partial class Table1
{
    public Table1()
    {
        this.something= new HashSet<something>();
    }
}
```

And my custom code for partial class `Table1`:

```
public partial class Table1
{
    public void Table1(string test)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You will also get more eyes if you include a tag for which language you are using (after you post your code.)

Comment: Are you sure this is the **exact** code that declares your parametrized constructor? Did you declare `public void Table1(string test)`?

Comment: Yes Bas, I had put void and that was the issue. Thanks for pointing my mistake!

Comment: So this is fixed then?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put a return type on a constructor.
You just need

public Table1(String test){
}

Not

Public void Table1(String test){

}

Your compiler is complaining because it thinks you are trying to declare a regular method with the same name as your constructor.  Drop the void and it because a second constructor.